# WPF Canvas Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, canvas

I'm rather new to WPF, so maybe this is a simple question. I have a class that derives from Canvas, let's call it MyCanvas. And I have a class, MyClass, that has a property of type MyCanvas. In XAML, I built a TabControl, so each TabItem binds to a MyClass object. Now, in the Content of every tab I want to display MyObject.MyCanvas.

How should I do that?

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <myCanvas:MyCanvas  Focusable="true" Margin="10" >
                <Binding Path="Canvas"></Binding>
            </myCanvas:MyCanvas>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use ContentPresenter

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
        <Grid> 
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyCanvas}" Focusable="true" Margin="10" />
        </Grid> 
    </DataTemplate> 
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ContentPresenter` and binding the contents to the property you want.  If the property is a descendent of `Canvas`, this should result in it simply displaying that content.  If the property was of another type, it would attempt to use a DataTemplate to render it.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, but I marked bniwredyc's as the solution because it was the first.

Comment: And more complete.  No worries... I voted up his answer as soon as I saw it.  :)